# Building an embedded linux yocto

Tags: linux, yocto

I try to build an embedded linux system for my raspberrypi3 board using yocto on Ubuntu 16.04 I use stable branch fido.
But I got this error:

```
    kamel@ThinkPad-E590:/opt/yocto/poky/build$ bitbake core-image-minimal
    Parsing recipes: 100% |########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:33
    Parsing of 1499 .bb files complete (0 cached, 1499 parsed). 2061 targets, 132 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
    NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

    Build Configuration:
    BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
    BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
    NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal"
    TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
    MACHINE           = "raspberrypi3"
    DISTRO            = "poky"
    DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.2.4"
    TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7ve vfp thumb neon vfpv4 callconvention-hard cortexa7"
    TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
    meta              
    meta-poky         
    meta-yocto-bsp    = "fido:e56be3cee517c5262486136dbd6d649b68c3a8b7"
    meta-oe           = "fido:997caf9146cd3797cd054e2adebd1fbb4df91911"
    meta-raspberrypi  = "fido:2a192261a914892019f4f428d7462bb3c585ebac"

    Initialising tasks: 100% |#####################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:06
    NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
    NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks


**ERROR:** *quilt-native-0.64-r0 do_populate_lic: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated: The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>*
```

How do I resolve these ?

Comment: have you ensured that pre-requisites are installed they are here https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#required-packages-for-the-host-development-system

Comment: I have install all pre-requisites:

     $ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat make xsltproc docbook-utils fop dblatex xmlto libsdl1.2-dev xterm install python-git

Comment: fido is a lot, but certainly not stable - rather massively end of life. See: [Yocto Releases](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases). I'd suggest to try again with warrior, zeus or thud.

Comment: I tried with warrior and thud, but I  got the same error !! :/

Comment: What is the default python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been taken to the [OpenEmbedded Development mailing list](http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-devel/2019-December/203569.html) and has been found to not be a problem with Yocto/OE but with the users specific building host.

Ubuntu 16.04 is confirmed as working.

Please try again with a clean container or build machine, and if that is not possible, please name any virtuallization/containerization/other magic that is in use here, as it is most likely the source of the problem.